# Node.js - Error: socket hang up

Tags: node.js, http, express

I try to get data from the json.placeholder API with a proxy domain. I'm authenticated by this proxy using a auth header. This auth header needs to be send every request. But I get a error:

```
error: { Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:331:15)
...
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

My code looks as follow:

```
app.get('/users/1', (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        host: 'velodrome.usefixie.com',
        port: 80,
        path: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' + req.path,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             Host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
            'Proxy-Authorization': `Basic ${new Buffer(auth).toString('base64')}`,
        }
    };

    const x = http.get(options, (request) => {
        request.on('data', (locations) => {
            buffer = new Buffer(locations);
        });
        request.pipe(res);
    }).on('error', (err) => console.log('error:', err));
    x.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `options.host` should be the remote host you want to call, e.g. `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` and your `options.path` should be the query string (url params) you want to use.

Currently you're calling `velodrome.usefixie.comhttp://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com{your req.path}:80`.

Have a look at these:

[Node.js docs, http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

And this

[How to make a http request](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/)

And also check out **request** and **axios** from npm, they are libraries made for making easier http requests in Node.